# Comparison between Writing non-blocking code vs Creating a big number of webserver workers

Tags: python, nginx, webserver, tornado, nonblocking

My web application's main functionality is a blocking method that will wait 1 to 5 seconds for I/O response. I can write the method's code in a non-blocking way by creating another thread and using a non-blocking framework like `Tornado`.

But I'm not sure about this solution's pros in comparison with using my blocking code on `flask` and `nginx` with a big amount of worker threads.

I know that this way will be more RAM consuming than the non-blocking way but in my case the whole procedure is not very big. The most important thing for me is to have a simple code and a good performance.

For more clearance I should say in this case the time consuming procedure is loading a url using `Ghost.py`.